# Javascript: Change image depending on multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is a question if it is even possible to create...and that with not that much knowlege of Javascript:

I have some cars with several "options", e.g.:

- type: sedan, cabriolet
- color: black, blue, red
- rims: rimA, rimB, rimC
- tyres: tyre1, tyre2, tyre3

In total that are 54 different cars, and for each I have a set of 3 images each.

They would all have a unique name based on the above values, something like this:

- sedan-black-rimA-tyre1.jpg
- sedan_blue-rimA-tyre2.jpg
- cabriolet-red-rimC-tyre1.jpg
- ...
- [type]-[color]-[rims]-[tyres].jpg

Now I would like to create a page where the "standard car" is already shown (Sedan, black, rimA, tyre1).

There are buttons in the corners labeled with the options type, color, rims, tyres - which open like an accordion and show the "values" as images. 
In each the standard values are already preselected.

Selecting different options, the shown image should change accordingly - ideally per ajax, so not to reload the whole page.

In the footer are some social buttons th share the custom car, therefore the link has to contain the values just selected.

Again, is such a page possible to create with medium javascript knowledge, and if so, could you hint me in the right direction where to find tutorials / more information on how to do it exactly (especially the part with the multiple "options/values")?

Thanks a bunch in advance,

Emil

Comment: Hi, Emil, and welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is too vague for this board. We prefer to solve concrete, specific problems with code you have. So, if you know some javascript, just start coding, and let us know when you're stuck - we'll be there to help you. For now, I'm voting to close your question, because, as stated, it's not on topic here. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

This is very doable, and you wouldn't even need to use Ajax.

Changing the `src` attribute of an image will update it immediately, so, if all of your image variations are already stored in the same directory, simply changing the file name dynamically . . . based on the values . . . would change the image that you were displaying.

There are TONS of resources out there to help you get started . . . enough, that I'm not even sure it makes sense to try and point you to one.  I'd suggest just doing some searches on the logic that you are looking for and then just diving in and giving it a shot.  Bring back what you've come up with, if you are having issues, and we can help you get through them.